# using a custom url on iis server instead of IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have hosted an Asp.Net MVC application on to IIS 8 in windows server 2012 and to open the webpage currently I use the address like 10.10.10.10. Is there anyways I can make it customized like www.example.com to access the page. I have done a bit of research but couldn't find a better way to do it.

I am using IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012 to disploy

Comment: You can put your custom host name in your DNS server. like myapp.mydomain.local.

Comment: Read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771629.aspx on how to bing a hostname to a specific site in IIS 8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 10.x.x.x address implies that it's on a local domain/network.

There are two easy ways you can do this:

1. Host your own DNS server and add an entry for www.example.com to resolve to 10.10.10.10
2. Edit your hosts file `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` adding a new line `10.10.10.10 www.example.com`

Note option 2, will only work for the computer you edit the hosts file on.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is! You will need to edit the "hosts" file:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Basically point that IP(10.10.10.10) to www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve domain name to IP. You can:

- use machine name instead of IP (like `http://serverName/pages...` ) or sometimes fully qualified domain name of the machine (like `http://serverName.my.organization.com/pages...` if your company have AD or internal DNS setup for that)
- if you have local DNS server for organization you can register DNS record with
- if your IP is public you can use public DNS servers to register the name with
- you can use local `hosts` file to provide DNS mapping on your local machine
- you can use Fiddler as proxy and resolve DNS names with it